# h₂ou̯is or h₃eu̯is

Tags: proto-indo-european

I wonder which variant of reconstruction of this word, meaning "sheep" in PIE is the correct.

Beekes gives ****h₃eu̯is***, Fortson gives ****h₂ou̯is***. Both are respected scholars, Fortson's source is the later. Who is correct?

Comment: I had provided an answer, but after discussion it seems it was not on point to what you are looking for.

Comment: Or to put it the other way, *owis is the late PIE form which had lost the laryngeals while the Proto-Indo-Hittite (early PIE) had laryngeals http://tinyurl.com/7wpsb7g

Comment: To clarify: are you asking what criteria are used to decide whether a root is h2o- vs. h3e-? That is, Xe- vs. X<super>w</super>e-

Comment: Yes. What laryngeal is predicted by the most modern theory. The vowels reconstructed adjanced to the laryngeals also differ.

Comment: The explanations about laryngeal theory that I have seen just say that word-initial *o was actually a combination of h3e and initial *a was h2e. But the reconstructions of Schleicher's tale in Wikipedia show the completely different reconstruction.

Comment: [Forston 2011](http://books.google.com/books/about/Indo_European_Language_and_Culture.html?id=bSxHgej4tKMC) gives h2o- for "sheep" but as I don't work in PIE studies, I don't know how universally agreed that is.

Comment: Well indeed Forston favors the first variant. But the other book I linked gives the other.

Comment: Also Wikipedia gives the second variant: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_Proto-Indo-European_roots/h%E2%82%83

Comment: Anixx, you have asked a number of questions related to PIE and accepted zero answers. I fear, though I'm not sure, that you are not looking for answers so much as looking to start discussions.

Comment: Your question in its current form has no answer because it is based on a wrong assumption. There is no such thing as the only one correct reconstructed form. They are different because different researchers subscribe to different hypotheses.

Comment: @AlexB. That wouldn't be a bad answer, actually. I mean, your first sentence (and the rest). :)

Comment: It would be even better it it described which researchers support which theory and why.

Comment: If you can read in Russian, you should read Herzenberg 2012 http://iling.spb.ru/comparativ/mater/tronsky2012/tronsky2012.pdf In that paper he compares major versions of Schleicher's fable.

Comment: @Alex, very interesting. Don't you want to make an answer? I am still reading.

Comment: @AlexB.: I agree with Alenanno and Anixx that you can contribute a good answer to this question based on what the different hypotheses are.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do it this weekend.